# Reportar Erro ao copiar arquivos e pastas utilizando ThreadPool

Tags: exceção, multithreading

Tenho uma aplicação Windows Form a qual copia arquivos e pastas para várias máquinas em rede.

Quando a cópia não é possível adiciona-se à um lista o nome da máquina e, no final, apresento em um *Listbox*.

O problema é que sempre que dispara um exceção em uma das *threads* eu não consigo dar um `throw Ex` para adicionar nessa lista.

```
public class Processo
{
    private ManualResetEvent _eventoReset;
    private int _threadIndex;
    private string _destino;
    private string _origem;

    public Processo(ManualResetEvent eventoReset, string origem, string destino)
    {
        this._eventoReset = eventoReset;
        this._origem = origem;
        this._destino = destino;
    }

    public void ThreadPoolCallback(Object threadContextIndex)
    {
        this._threadIndex = (int)threadContextIndex;
        ExecutaTarefas();
        this._eventoReset.Set();
    }

    private void ExecutaTarefas()
    {
        try
        {
            FileSystem.CopyDirectory(_origem, _destino, true);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }            
    }
}
```

Na aplicação

```
int numeroDeElementos = maquinas.Count();

        ManualResetEvent[] statusEventos = new ManualResetEvent[numeroDeElementos];            
        Processo[] tarefaArray = new Processo[numeroDeElementos];

        for (int i = 0; i < maquinas.Count(); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Ping ping = new Ping();
                PingReply retorno = ping.Send(maquinas[i].pc);

                if (retorno.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    statusEventos[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);                       
                    Processo thr = new Processo(statusEventos[i], origem, destino));

                    tarefaArray[i] = thr;                        
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(thr.ThreadPoolCallback, i);                          
                }
                else
                {
                    listaMaquinas.Add(string.Format("{0} Fila: {1} Posição: {2} não foi possivel conectar ao computador. ", maquinas[i].auto, maquinas[i].fila, maquinas[i].posicao));
                }
            }                
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                listaMaquinas.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1} - Fila:{2} - Posição:{3} - Erro: {4}", maquinas[i].auto, maquinas[i].pc, maquinas[i].fila, maquinas[i].posicao, ex.Message));
            }

            progressBar1.Value = x;
            x += 1;
        }
 foreach (WaitHandle doneEvent in statusEventos)
        {
            if (doneEvent != null)
            {
                doneEvent.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        if (listaMaquinas.Count() > 0)
        {
            listBox1.DataSource = listaMaquinas;
            MessageBox.Show("As maquinas listadas não puderam ser atualizadas.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Atualização concluida com sucesso.");
        }
```

Comment: Ainda bem que você não consegue dar um `throw ex;`. É a última coisa que você deveria fazer com uma exceção. Ou talvez penúltima, capturar `Exception` também está muito errado. Eu escrevi uma quantidade enorme de respostas sobre o assunto porque quase ninguém sabe usar exceções. Tem muita coisa para ler e não deve parar só nas minhas respostas, mas é fundamental aprender usar o recurso corretamente. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:101+[exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o]

Answer (score 1):

Você está cometendo alguns enganos no seu código - por exemplo lançando uma exceção dentro de uma thread e esperando capturá-la em um catch fora dela (não é assim que funciona).

O código abaixo é quase um pseudocódigo, só para, junto com os comentários que adicionei, dar uma idéia de como prosseguir:

```
private void ExecutaTarefas()
{
    try
    {
        FileSystem.CopyDirectory(_origem, _destino, true);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        // não relance a exceção e nem lance nenhuma exceção
        // que você não vá tratar dentro da própria thread a não ser que
        // você assine os eventos de "Application" para tratamento de exceções em threads.

        // em vez disso, registro o erro:

        this.erro = "não foi possível copiar " + _origem + " para " + _destino
    }            
}
```

...

```
    for (int i = 0; i < maquinas.Count(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply retorno = ping.Send(maquinas[i].pc);

            if (retorno.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                statusEventos[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);                       
                Processo thr = new Processo(statusEventos[i], origem, destino));

                tarefaArray[i] = thr;                        
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(thr.ThreadPoolCallback, i);                          
            }
            else
            {
                listaMaquinas.Add(string.Format("{0} Fila: {1} Posição: {2} não foi possivel conectar ao computador. ", maquinas[i].auto, maquinas[i].fila, maquinas[i].posicao));
            }
        }                
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Não espere capturar aqui a exceção lançada dentro da thread pois isso não vai funcionar!
            // Provavelmente você pode eliminar esse tratamento de exceção.
        }
```

Você pode substituir o loop abaixo

```
    foreach (WaitHandle doneEvent in statusEventos)
    {
        if (doneEvent != null)
        {
            doneEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }
```

Por:

```
WaitHandle.WaitAll(statusEventos)
```

Por fim, depois de todas as threads terminarem, você percorre todos os seus processos e verifica quais deles falharam:

```
foreach (Processo processo: tarefaArray)
{
    if (processo.erro != null)
        listaMaquinas.Add(processo.erro);
}
```

Repito que é só uma idéia de lógica para a solução do problema! Verificar se a propriedade "erro" é null, por exemplo, pode ser muito simplório. Mas a idéia geral é:

- capture a exceção dentro da própria thread;
- registre os detalhes do erro em propriedades do processo que executou como thread;
- uma vez concluída a thread, verifique as propriedades do processo para saber dos seus resultados.